# Using prompt with some color picker

Tags: javascript, colors, prompt, picker, execcommand

Can I using prompt with some color color picker? Now, my code is:

```
case 'foreColor':
    var color = prompt('Define a base color or apply a hexadecimal color code for advanced color:', '');
    document.execCommand('foreColor', false, color);
    break;
```

And how can I do this color picker? I would like to define a few colors for the user to click, not typing.